# Webflux return object in the middle of the stream

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a scenario like:

```
return Mono.just(id)
    .flatMap(id -> checkAccess(id))
    .then(generateBusinessObject())
    .then(postMessageOnBus())
    .onErrorResume(throwable -> return Mono.error())
    .toFuture();
```

The problem is that I want to return the generated business object but also publish a message on a messagebus if and only if checkAccess is true and generateBusinessObject is successful.
Both generateBusinessObject and postMessageOnBus are also Mono objects.

I tried different solutions but without success.
Any advice is more than welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you "flatMap" over something which, as I understood, returns a boolean? I would just "filter" and apply some "defaultIfEmpty"; also - would you like to run mentioned tasks in parallel, or as now - one-by-one?

Comment: I want to run them one-by-one. Method checkAccess returns Mono<Boolean> if successful or not and Mono<Error> if something occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Mono.zipWith in order to achieve the goal.

```
generateBusinessObject() -> returns Mono
postMessageOnBus() -> returns Mono
```

The fix looks like this

```
businessMono.zipWith(busResponseMono).
.map(Tuple2::getT1)
.onErrorResume(throwable -> return Mono.error())
.toFuture();
```

This way, the business object is returned only after both Mono objects are successful and, at the same time, posting the message on the bus comes after creating the business object.